# kotlin - camera does not move in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I am trying to move the camera on a google map to show another place
when clicking the zoom controls

For some reason beyond me I cannot figure out why.
It seems to toast just fine, but the camera will not change positions.

Please help

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
            googleMap.clear()
            googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener {}

            googleMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true
            googleMap.uiSettings.isRotateGesturesEnabled = false

            googleMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener {
                if(it == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_API_ANIMATION){
                    mContext?.toast("Camera Move Started")
                    with(googleMap){
                        moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689), 10f))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: stopping which animation?

Comment: As per Doc https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/events#camera_change_events         
REASON_API_ANIMATION indicates that the API has moved the camera in response to a non-gesture user action, such as tapping the zoom button, tapping the My Location button, or clicking a marker.